# Why (x+iy)^2 is equal to x^2-y^2+2ixy and not equal to x^2+y^2+2ixy?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why $(x+iy)^2$ is equal to $x^2-y^2+2ixy$ and not equal to $x^2+y^2+2ixy$ ? I have seen this confusion in the field of complex analytic.

Comment: What’s the value of $i^2$?

Comment: Dear @FrancescoBernardini, $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Then what’s your doubt exactly?

Comment: So $(iy)^2=i^2 y^2=-y^2$.

Comment: Dear @FrancescoBernardini and other guys, my confusion was due to lake of attention. Thanks all very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x+iy)^2=(x+iy)(x+iy)=x^2+2ixy+i^2y^2=x^2+2ixy-y^2$.  (Perhaps use the FOIL method for multiplying two binnomials if you know it.)

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+iy)^2 = x^2 + 2ixy + (iy)^2 $$
$$= x^2 + 2ixy + i^2y^2 = x^2 + 2ixy + (-y^2) =  x^2 + 2ixy -y^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$(x+iy)^2 = x^2 + (iy)^2+ 2ixy = x^2+ i^2y^2 + 2ixy = x^2+(-1)y^2+2ixy= x^2-y^2+2ixy$